# In Android Studio, can we store a history point?

Tags: android, android-studio, history

it's like when you write code A, you markup this state, then you go on editing code A into code B (making lots of steps) and when you want to come back to state A, it's still available?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Comment: You can undo until you reach the state A, provided that the undo cache is not exhausted to its limit. Or, it is better to use any revision control system like Git, SVN, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click the file which you want to revert and choose `Local History` and check the history of changes made to the file and revert back to whatever you needed.

Refer the image attached below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

“Version Control System” (VCS)

[**subversion with Android studio**](https://weeklyitblogs.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/subversion-with-android-studio/)

- github,  bitbucket (git)

  [github example](http://www.goprogramming.space/connecting-an-android-studio-project-with-github/)

  [excellent github guide](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)

  [bitbucket example](http://www.goprogramming.space/connecting-android-studio-project-with-bitbucket/)
- svn (subversion)
- mercurial (hg)
- local

Answer (score 1):

While the best method is using a revision control system, it is also possible to  roll back changes using the built in Local History feature of Android Studio.

To revert to an older version of a file from within Android Studio just select Local History from the context menu for any text file in your project. This displays the history of edits for the given file and provides a differences view to compare versions and revert to an older version.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find local history on Android Studio try this:

1. press on VCS menu once (you will not see it)
2. press on VCS again you should see it at the top option.

At least this is how it's working now in mac (Android Studio ~2.2)

Answer (score 0):

in Android studio chipmunk
go to:
git-> vcs operations-> show history.
You will find mentioned by BrentM built-in Local History feature of Android Studio